# Commerce Kikstart rules how to

Tags: commerce, rules, notifications

I'm trying to make a subscription product with "Commerce subscription products" module, so I've stuck here, on how to edit rule for subscription to last for 30 days, that is the first, part, second is, is there some good tutorial on rules, in drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, what your problem with Commerce subscription products is, without more detail.

Randy Fay have made a lot of [screen casts about Commerce](http://vimeo.com/user5912539/videos/search%3acommerce/sort%3anewest) which also include configuration about Rules. You might be able to find a more better tutorial on Rules, but Randy does a really good job on stepping through different tasks in Commerce. There isn't a screen cast about subscriptions, but you should be able to get a lot of help from some of these anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rules Framework](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework) simply explained in its entirety is well presented by Johan Falk here.

I recommend any of [these tutorials](http://dev.nodeone.se/sv) highly.