# How can I manually add a subscription to an account using Commerce Subscription Product module?

Tags: commerce

I am using the [Commerce Subscription Product module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp) 1.x and I would like to add a few accounts manually that have a subscription. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've honestly only quickly glanced at it right now, but as far as I can tell, a valid subscription is simply the field `field_commerce_sp_time` having a value, in number of weeks the subscription is valid from today.

Thus, you should be able to simply edit the `user entity` as you usually would, and set any number of week you want. Note that the module ships with relevant permissions for editing the field, so you need to have the `field_commerce_sp_validity` permissions.

Similarly, you could directly insert the relevant value into the database with

```
db_insert('field_commerce_sp_time', 'fcst')
  ->fields(array(
    'entity_id' => $uid,
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'value' => $number_of_weeks,
  ))
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only add the expiration date to the users account, but will not create a scheduled rule to actually remove the role.

Comment: i take that back, after running cron the scheduled rule is created

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19723/commerce-kikstart-rules-how-to has some helpful information on rules.